# AWS CDK : how to get 'Arn' of an already created role or policy by their names

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I know the name of the role or policy that is already created. Can someone let me know whats the best way to get the 'Arn' using the role name/policy name using AWS CDK.

My use case is to use 'Arn' to import the resource and use it while creating other resources

Comment: You can import both roles and managed policies by name instead of the full ARN.

Comment: can you please share details on how to import roles and policies using their name. I am only aware of the option for 'Arn'

Comment: Did you check the docs?

Answer (score 1):

Like most ARNs, IAM policy ARNs are structured values, not opaque.  They take the format:  `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/MyPolicyName`.  Note region is undefined.  Use string concatenation to turn your policy name into an ARN. Or use the Stack's [formatArn method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Stack.html#formatwbrarncomponents):

```js
// this: cdk.Stack -> partition, region, account are the stack's values by default
const arn = this.formatArn({
  region: '',
  service: 'iam',
  resource: 'policy',
  resourceName: 'MyPolicyName',
  arnFormat: cdk.ArnFormat.SLASH_RESOURCE_NAME,
});
```